# number input in shell

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I want to get inputs(numbers) from user  "last". And after that I will use numbers for evaluation. But my program doesn't work correctly.
Here is my code :

```
echo "Enter numbers until -last- "
while read line
do
     array=("${array[@]}" $line)  
     if [ "$array[-1]" != "last" ]
     then
     break
     fi
done
 ......
 .....
 echo "average numbers of this blablabla " #this part is correct
```

It works correctly when I use space button but I have to use enter button. And it doesn't accept "last" input.

How can I implement it?

Comment: What do you want the program to do with input after the line that matches "last"?  If it is ignored, then why bother checking for that string?  Just read until end of input.  And why so verbose?  Imagine if grep printed out 'please enter a pattern to match', followed by 'please enter the text you would like to match against'.

Comment: I want to inputs (they will be numbers ) write before -last-. Last is my last element in the inputs. I will estimate average of this numbers . I want to store numbers in an array(inputArray) and ı need t read inputs until the word -last- @WilliamPursell .  Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Don't add the entry to the array until you know it isn't `last`.  How do you reset the array to empty?  Your example output doesn't show `last` being entered for the single-item set {5}; your example output doesn't show `last` being entered for the three-item set {5, 10, 11}.  What gives?  You should really show an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  What you've shown is only a part of the code when we look at the example output.

Comment: my code doens't wor with "last". If I don't need last, it works correctly. But when I write last , it works like the last ouput ı mean it is an infinitive loop with -last- word. HHhow can I fix it ? @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Do **NOT** remove your question once you have a semblance to an answer.  That is totally non-kosher.

Comment: okey @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop populates `inputArray` with the lines you enter (no checking that they're actually numbers) up until you enter a line containing only `last`:

```
inputArray=()
echo "Enter numbers until -last- "
while read line
do
     if [ "$line" = "last" ]
     then break
     fi
     inputArray+=("$line")  
done
echo "${inputArray[@]}"
```

You can take it from there.  Note that the entry isn't added to the array until you know it isn't `last`.

Some people will insist you should use `read -r` instead of just `read`; feel free to ignore them once you know what you're risking (see [read](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read) in the Bash manual).